# A central limit theorem for dependent random variable.

Tags: probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Suppose that $u_{j}$ is a sequence of iid standard Gaussian random variable, i.e. 
$$
u_j\stackrel{d}{=}\text{N}(0,1).
$$
Call $\mu_r=\mathbb{E}[|u_j|^r]$. I need to find the asymptotic distribution of the random variable 
$$
\sqrt{n}\,\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}u_j^2-\frac{\mu_1^{-2}}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|u_j|\,|u_{j+1}|\right)=n^{-1/2}\,\sum_{j=1}^n|u_j|\left(|u_j|-\mu_1^{-2}\,|u_{j+1}|\right)=n^{-1/2}\,\sum_{j=1}^n\xi_j,
$$
where $\xi_j=|u_j|\left(|u_j|-\mu_1^{-2}\,|u_{j+1}|\right)$. However, since the $\xi_j$ are dependent, I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(\xi_j)_{j\le N}$ and $(\xi_j)_{j\ge N+k}$ are independent for $k\ge 2$, the stochastic process $(\xi_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ is strongly($\alpha$-) mixing. More precisely, we can say that the strong mixing coefficient $\alpha(k)$ vanishes for $k\geq 2$. Note that $E\xi_j =0$ and every $p$-th moment $E|\xi_j|^p$ is finite. By [$\alpha$-mixing central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Dependent%20Processes), we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j \to_d \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)
$$
where $\sigma^2 = E[\xi_j^2] +2 E[\xi_j \xi_{j+1}]\ge 0$.